# How to Enable State and Country Picklists?

Tags: administration, picklist

### How to Enable State and Country Picklists?

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklist_enable.htm&language=en_US) says:
**Your Name | Setup | Data Management | State and Country Picklists.**

However, I can't see it under **Data Management**.

> Type: Developer Edition
>   Org version: Spring '13
>   Date of org creation: 2012-05-24 11:07:41
>   Instance: AP1

Comment: Make sure you understand the limitations of it before you turn it on in production.  The Spring'13 release of it seems to require a great deal of monkeying around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its under pilot program and hence first you may need to contact salesforce and ask them to enable for your org then you may be able to access .

This is in production as of September 11 2013, this is now officially deployed.

http://www.salesforcetutorial.com/salesforce-winter14-release-notes/

Comment: And as @StevenHerod says, "the Spring '13 release of it seems to require a great deal of monkeying around". It has a great deal of post-implementation steps if enabled in an existing org.

Comment: I wrote a three-part blog post (http://techblog.appirio.com/2013/04/enabling-state-country-as-picklists-in.html) on how to enable it on Spring '13 orgs. Steven is quite right, it's not trivial at all, and could break managed packages quite easily if they rely on the standard state / country fields.